# issue installing npm package, react-circular-progressbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, web-development-server

When I install react-circular-progressbar into my react projects it show an error why?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: nadeems-portfolio@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-circular-progressbar@2.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-circular-progressbar
npm ERR!   react-circular-progressbar@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/nadeem/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nadeem/.npm/_logs/2020-12-05T09_58_59_238Z-deb
```

Comment: Did you run npm install?

Comment: yes i have run 'npm install'

Comment: Try deleting the package-lock.json file and then running npm install again.

Comment: I think react-circular-progress doesnot support react 17.0.0 am i correct

Comment: @dhruvtailor its working fine when we run npm start or anything else but react-router-progress installing makes an error on installation so i think there is no mean to delete node_modules because all other thing are working well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because one of the depencies can not be resolved combined with your current dependencies.

The following part indicates that ciruclar-progressbar (version 2.0.3) requires react 15 or 16 as a peer dependency, and you are using a newer version in your dependency list.

```
Could not resolve dependency: peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-circular-progressbar@2.0.3
```

There are a few solutions;

- Downgrade the package that doesn't fit in the constraints of the package that you want to install
- Look for a version of the package that you are trying to install that has updated their peer dependencies to include react 17
- use `npm install <package-name> --force` to ignore it (really not recommended, unless you have manually verified there are no incompatibilities)
- use  `npm install <package-name> --legacy-peer-deps`.

The first two options are deduced from the error you have given. Whereas the last two options are provided in the error itself.

Comment: I have confirmed that react-circular-progress@2.0.3 works fine with react@17.0.1.

Comment: Maybe a cached older version of 2.0.3? I'm not sure. There's also not too much more info to be gotten from that error message. But as there's not a single upvote yet, i'll not be putting in any more effort :)